# Utility and meaning of the relative setting in Scheme theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm sorry if my question is rather trivial, but I'm starting to learn scheme theory and I have a very basic question.

When talking about schemes I see that very often, instead of taking "a point of a scheme $X$", is customary to take a $T$-point of $X$ (where $T$ is another scheme) i.e. a morphism $T\rightarrow X$. In this way, under the hypothesis that both $X$ and $T$ are schemes over a field $k$, we obtain a scheme $X\times_k T$ over $T$ (this is also called "base change" as I understand). My question is: why is this "relative setting" so useful and so what is the importance of the $T$-points? In other words, why can't we just consider usual points, as we do for topological spaces or complex varieties?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a very good question and I cannot give you a full answer. I can, however, elaborate on the connection between the functor of points and products. One main problem with actual points of a scheme is that they don't behave well on taking products. That is: if $X$ and $Y$ are schemes over $k$, then the set of points of $X \times_{k} Y$ is not, in general, the product of the sets of points. However, the set of $T$-points of $X \times_{k} Y$ is the same as the product of the sets of $T$-points. This is actually how products are defined categorically.

Comment: Contd: A lot of useful concepts in algebraic geometry, such as separatedness, properness, are most cleanly defined using the fiber product so having a notion of "point" that behaves well under fiber product is very useful.

Comment: Yes, I know that many properties of morphisms such as separatedness and properness are maintained after base change.. So why is this so important?

Comment: Usually, one means something else by «relative setting»: that one does not really interest oneself with schemes $X$ but with schemes $X$ endowed with a morphism to some base $S$, that is morphisms of schemes $X\to S$. This is quite different from what your quesstion is about.

Comment: As you probably know, the topological points of a scheme do not determine the scheme. E.g. $Spec(k)$ and $Spec(k[x]/x^2)$ are different schemes both consisting of a single closed point. The "points" in the sense you describe, however, DO determine the scheme. This is the Yoneda philosophy. It is often easier to describe what a scheme $X$ is in terms of how other schemes $T$ "see" $X$, i.e. what morphisms exist from $T$ to $X$.

Comment: For example, what is a Grassmannian as a scheme? You can view it as affine patches which glue together in places where certain minors don't vanish, or you can view it as a scheme whose $T$ points are subbundles of the trivial $T$ bundle (of prescribed rank). The latter is a lot more in tune with general intuition of what a Grassmannian should be.

Comment: There is a confusion in your question: if $T$ and $X$ both lie over Spec $k$, then you can form $X \times_k T$.  If furthermore you have a morphism $T \to X$ (compatible with the morphisms to Spec $k$), then you can reinterpret this as a section of the natural projection $X \times_k T \to T$.  So essentially you are confusing the ideas of base-change and of $T$-valued points; while these ideas are definitely related, the conceptual connection is a bit more subtle than what your (mis)phrasing suggests.